# Using reflection I need to invoke a method with (of T) parameter

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make this code with reflection since I want it to manage Technician and other types too.

```
m_Technician = m_Entities.CreateObject(Of Technician)()     'line#1
m_Technician.IDTechnician = Guid.NewGuid()
m_Entities.AddObject("Technicians", m_Technician)
```

I used this code with reflection to fill the entity and it work perfectly.

```
m_Entity = GetType(RFOPSEntities). _
           GetMethod(FillMethodName).Invoke(m_Entities, New Object() {uniqueKey})
```

So I tried something like that for the line #1 :

```
m_Entity = GetType(RFOPSEntities). _
           GetMethod("CreateObject"). _
           Invoke(m_Entities, New Object({GetType("Technician")})
```

I think my difficulty is to pass the `(Of Technician)`

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) function to produce a generic MethodInfo from which you can invoke.

```
m_Entity = GetType(RFOPSEntities). _
           GetMethod("CreateObject").MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Technician)). _
           Invoke(m_Entities)
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, It work great. I forgot it was a generic method, that make sense.

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out how to do the second line wich is to set the property: m_Technician.IDTechnician = Guid.NewGuid()
it could be m_entity.IDProduct = Guid.NewGuid(), I'm tryingto figure out myselft, but sometimes help don't hurt. Thank you

Comment: @Francis glad it worked! Assuming that m_Technician is an object and you're wanting to do this totally by reflection, then it'd have to be along the lines of m_Entity.GetType().GetProperty("IDTechnician").SetValue(m_Entity, Guid.NewGuid(), Nothing)